# is it possible to batch requests to google classroom in AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am working on an app that is uploading data to Google Classroom using AppScript. I use two methods a lot:

```js
/*
 *@description adding grade to the submission
 *@param courseId {string} id of clasroom in which there is coursework that we are intrested in
 *@param courseWorkId {string} id of coursework in which there is submission that we are intrested in
 *@param submId {string} submission id of submission to which we want to set mark*/
function setMark(courseId, courseWorkId, submIdd, mark) {
  var maark = parseFloat(mark) || 0
  if (maark < 0) {
    maark = 0
  }
  var studentSubmissionRes = {
      'assignedGrade': maark,
      'draftGrade': maark
    }
  var extra = {
    'updateMask': 'assignedGrade,draftGrade'
  };
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmissionRes,
    courseId, courseWorkId, submIdd, extra)
}

/**
 *@description  addind link to the submission
 *@param fileUrl {string} url of file we want to add to submission
 *@param courseId {string} id of clasroom in which there is coursework that we are intrested in
 *@param courseWorkId {string} id of coursework in which there is submission that we are intrested in
 *@param submId {string} submission id of submission to which we want to add the link
 */
function setLinkTosubmission(fileUrl, courseId, courseWorkId, submId) {
  var request = ModifyAttachmentsRequest = {
    'addAttachments': [{
      'link': {
        'url': fileUrl
      }
    }]
  }
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.modifyAttachments(request, courseId, courseWorkId, submId)
}
```

Both of them work, but i would like to improve performance and batch requests to add link or grade, as is possible in Google Sheets API, but I cannot find a way to do this.

Also, is there a possibility to batch update text in many documents in at once?

Answer (score 2):

The [Classroom Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/classroom) does not support batching requests. For that reason, you will have to implement the code that creates the body of the batch request without its support, and send it afterwards using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). See below:

#### Example

```js
function main() {
  var body = [
    {
      method: "PATCH",
      endpoint: "/v1/courses/134529639?updateMask=name",
      requestBody: {"name": "Course 1"}
    },
    {
      method: "PATCH",
      endpoint: "/v1/courses/134529901?updateMask=section",
      requestBody: {"section": "Section 2"}
    }
  ];

  var url = "https://classroom.googleapis.com/batch";
  var boundary = "batch_foobarbaz";
  var contentId = 0;
  var data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  for (var i in body) {
    data += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n";
    data += "Content-ID: " + ++contentId + "\r\n\r\n";
    data += body[i].method + " " + body[i].endpoint + "\r\n";
    data += body[i].requestBody ? "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" : "\r\n";
    data += body[i].requestBody ? JSON.stringify(body[i].requestBody) + "\r\n" : "";
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  }
  var payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes();
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
    payload: payload,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

In this case, a batch request is created containing two different `PATCH` calls to the API. The obtained response will look somewhat like the following:

```js
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length: response_total_content_length
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-item1:12930812@classroom.example.com>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type application/json
Content-Length: response_part_1_content_length

{
  "id": "134529639",
  "name": "Course 1",
  "section": "Section 1",
  "ownerId": "116269102540619633451",
  "creationTime": "2015-06-25T14:23:56.535Z",
  "updateTime": "2015-06-25T14:33:06.583Z",
  "enrollmentCode": "6paeflo",
  "courseState": "PROVISIONED",
  "alternateLink": "http://classroom.google.com/c/MTM0NTI5NjM5"
}
--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-item2:12930812@classroom.example.com>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: response_part_2_content_length

{
  "id": "134529901",
  "name": "Course 1",
  "section": "Section 2",
  "ownerId": "116269102540619633451",
  "creationTime": "2015-06-25T14:23:08.761Z",
  "updateTime": "2015-06-25T14:33:06.490Z",
  "enrollmentCode": "so75ha5",
  "courseState": "PROVISIONED",
  "alternateLink": "http://classroom.google.com/c/MTM0NTI5OTAx"
}
--batch_foobarbaz--
```

#### Reference

- [Batching Requests for Google Apps Scripts](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f167b9280a8e710804e4061571b53fb9)
- [Google Classroom API - Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch)

Comment: thank you for a response ! I will try to implement it , It is generally very usefull example for many things  while using app script !

Comment: Glad you liked my answer @Jagiellonczyk, kindly consider [Accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case it solves your original problem. In addition, please don't hesitate to publish another comment or question if you have any doubts with the answer. Cheers!

Comment: To be honest I have problems implementing this method I tried first to apply it to batch send marks but without success below link to methods and error message I would really apreciate Your comment  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rtBGfyULxP6t2m_snMsdGa8ZOgINcpt7m5A1puK7Qn4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There is also problem that I did not spotted before that the batch service as in above reference will be oon impossible to use because of Google migration