# Seeking Batch Grade Patch for API Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I can change the grade of a single student submission. I want to change a batch of grades for all students who completed the task.

A loop will not work. GAPI returns an error.

Is there a batch function I could use with a list of names?

Comment: Have you reviewed this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731751/is-it-possible-to-batch-requests-to-google-classroom-in-appscript]?

Comment: Thank you! I think the method is deprecated now, though. Google changed their batch system as of 12 Aug 2020. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch